# Issue with notification on android 7

Tags: android, android-notifications

**I have problem with notification on Philips s318 android 7**

I display a custom message and it works fine on all devices, but for some reason it stretches and breaks the markup. I do not understand what could be the reason. maybe the reason is in the system height of messages in android 7 or the whole point is that I'm using RelativeLayout

[image]

And how it correctly look like on other devices

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivAlert"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_notification_ram_alert" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/ivAlert"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btnRemove"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivAlert"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="#4E4F5A"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        tools:text="@string/notification_junk_description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSubtitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btnRemove"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivAlert"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColor="#4E4F5A"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        tools:text="@string/notification_junk_description" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRemove"
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_green"
        android:text="@string/notification_remove"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Show method

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notification_alarm_channel2);
        if (AFApplication.getInstance().getFirebaseRemoteConfig().getBoolean("new_push_time")) {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(bigIcon);
        } else {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_alert);
        }
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
        mBuilder.setContentText(message);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        mBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_push);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTitle, title);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tvSubtitle, message);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.ivAlert, bigIcon);
        mBuilder.setCustomContentView(remoteViews);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use android:layout_height="wrap_content" for your RelativeLayout.